# why doesnt my phone charge from external batteries?

Tags: battery, charging

My BLU Win JR will not charge from either of my external battery packs and I tried multiple cables. My tablet and other devices charge just fine from the batteries. These are my batteries:

1. [B00C13YSIO - Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C13YSIO)
2. [B00BB5GRFU - Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BB5GRFU)

Comment: The phone itself is working fine with your regular charger?

Comment: Yes, charges fine using wall charger.

Comment: it looks like there are different outputs for different devices. have you tried both? Also have you tried charging other Windows Phone devices?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both outputs. BTW, my Dell tablet and kid's kindle fire hd charges fine using the both of my external backups.

Comment: can you try any other cable / external battery etc?

Comment: I am a doofus. I tried it on my friends battery and it worked. Then I checked again on my battery... and it worked. I apologize for wasting everyone's time. Now, how best to close out this question?

Comment: Do you know why it didn't work in the beginning? If so, post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise you can request the question to be deleted.

Comment: I can only guess that my cables were not good, but it's strange because I tried more than one. I think I'll do some more experimenting before I answer and close.